# black window with android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb

I program on Eclipse for Android. But I have a problem with the Android emulator.
When I run the emulator, I get a black window and the error "this emulator is already running".
I already tried restarting Eclipse and ADB but it does not work, reinstalling Eclipse fixes the problem until it comes back.

Comment: thank for your response.
but from the console, it does not start, and I see the same log

Comment: what settings u have for your emulator ?

Comment: adb is not the emulator, but a tool for talking to it. See if adb works from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think two emulators are working just close all the emulators and re run the program

u can create a new emulator from window-avd manager